# Need a jquery script that shows alert when you mouseover on each list a tag

Tags: jquery

if list a tag href is mens you display alert('men') and so on. if womem you display alert('women')

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mainItem").mouseover(function () {
        var a = $('li a').each(
            function () {
                if ($(a).attr('href') == "/Pages/Men") {
                    alert('men');
                }
                else if ($(a).attr('href') == "/Pages/Women") {
                    alert('women');
                }
                else if ($(a).attr('href') == "/Pages/Services") {
                    alert('services');
                }
            });

    });

});
```

Comment: Inside each() method you don't need to use $(a), instead use $(this).attr('href')  For example:  if ($(a).attr('href') == "/Pages/Men")  should be  if ($(this).attr('href') == "/Pages/Men") {

Comment: Samir you are correct but it is displaying all alerts. I just need alert for the li a hover over. so if i hover over an a tag and it has an href containing men then it should display alert('men')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use $(this), not $(a)...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('li a').on("mouseenter", 
                function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('href') == "/Pages/Men") {
                        alert('men');
                    }
                    else if ($(this).attr('href') == "/Pages/Women") {
                        alert('women');
                    }
                    else if ($(this).attr('href') == "/Pages/Services") {
                        alert('services');
                    }
                });

    });
```

and also you dont need `var = a`, if you dont use it afterwards.

**from your comment: you should attach event on `a` it self...**

another thing! It is good practice to cache the $(this) for better performance:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

and then:

```
if ($this.attr('href') == "/Pages/Men") {
    alert('men');
}
```

and so on...